# Stylizing the assignment operator in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

R contains assignment operators such as this:  <-
I have seen code snippets where this operator is displayed as a unified arrow rather than being broken up into the less than symbol (<) and a minus sign (-).
This is obviously a styling option to 'beautify' the code. However, I am unable to find how to accomplish this.

See the images below to understand what I meant:

1. Broken assignment operator

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/18128531/27059158-6c0ed8a6-5018-11e7-9b02-6e7f5c556ab0.png

2. Unified assignment operator

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tbradley1013/rstudio-theme/master/www/merbivore-custom.png

Comment: The stylized assignment operator is only available in specific fonts that use programming ligatures. I believe the font in question is [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode). If you install that font, then in RStudio go to Global Options -> Appearance and select Editor Font -> Fira Code, then you will get the custom assignment arrows.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks a ton! This solves the issue. I had no idea that that these 'ligatures' are part of a font pack rather than the IDE itself.